# Euclidean distance in spark 2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to calculate euclidean distance of two vectors. I have the following dataframe:

```
root
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- episodeFeatures: vector (nullable = true)

import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.{MLUtils}
val jP2 = jP.withColumn("dist", MLUtils.fastSquaredDistance("features", 5, "episodeFeatures", 5))
```

I get an error like so:

```
error: method fastSquaredDistance in object MLUtils cannot be accessed in object org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
```

Is there a way to access that private method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MLUtils` are internal package, and even if wasn't for that, it couldn't be used on `Columns` or (guessing from the version) `ml` vectors. You have to design your own `udf`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

val euclidean = udf((v1: Vector, v2: Vector) => ???)  // Fill with preferred logic

val jP2 = jP.withColumn("dist", euclidean($"features", $"episodeFeatures"))
```